# Using wordpress for a journal - How to restrict access to all but a mobile client?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, wordpress, iphone

I'm looking to start keeping a journal for my life so i can archive events and tag them etc while at the same time making it as easy as possible for me to update (so I actually stick to using it). I use wordpress a lot and think it will fit the bill, but would like to restrict access to it as much as possible. I plan on using Apache directory allow/deny rules based on networks and domain names, but the one area I'd like to find a workaround for is making an exception for my iphone so i can make posts from it. I can't seem to find any dyndns clients that I can run on there to give me a static domain to make an exception for in Apache so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction if they knew of anything else that may work.

PS- i know there is a remote publishing option using email that I could use, but that wouldn't be my first choice... a solid backup plan however.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict access based on User agent, something like this:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPhone" let_me_in
<Directory /docroot>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=let_me_in
</Directory>
```

Comment: That would allow everyone with an iphone to access it .. I suggest http basic username/password authentication instead.

Comment: oh this is an interesting possibility...

Answer (score 1):

Get a secure server using ssh and putty and jot down your notes with vim or something. If it needs to be private why bother hosting it on wordpress?

Comment: for tagging/taxonomy/searching sake, while staying easy enough to use so that updating it is a seamless process in my life. I'm not looking to use it to keep critical data secure, I just don't want irrelevant data flowing out to the net. I'm thinking the use case would be like this:
"today i researched topic XYZ at work and found concerns with ABC <tags: work, XYZ, ABC>" and "fixed the garage door. found a loose bolt and lack of grease which fixed it <tags: home, garage, repair>" this way when i remember having done something before i can quickly find out what happened when and build timelines